# Should I sanitize user input upon 'before_validate' or 'before_save'?

Tags: security, web-applications

If I receive user input, does it make any difference if I validate first and then sanitize before saving it to the database?

**Or is there any risk in validating unsanitized input?**

(when I say 'sanitize' I mainly mean stripping out any HTML tags)

UPDATE & CLARIFICATION:

I wouldn't put HTML tags into the database. I would sanitize the input before saving it - but after validating against my model. The reason the validation and sanitization are separate is because they are separate libraries - the only question is whether I should call 'sanitize' upon 'before_validate' or upon 'before_save'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you separating HTML stripping (or escaping) from other validation?  Isn't it all the same thing?

And why would you put HTML tags into the database only to strip them later?  Doesn't that mean that your database is temporarily incorrect?

I don't see why you're separating "validation" from "sanitize".  They're two sides of the same coin.  Do *everything* you can to make sure the data is perfect before committing it to the database.

---

"the only question is whether I should call 'sanitize' upon 'before_validate' or upon 'before_save'."

The distinction is too subtle for words.  You must do both.  Generally, you do not want to try and validate HTML.

Therefore, it's only sensible if you (1) "sanitize" to strip HTML tags and then (2) validate what's left.

I'm not sure how else you could do it.

Answer (score 1):

The only risk I can think of is if you are performing extensive client-side validation. If you were validating and then spitting the values back onto the page in your error messages then you could have an issue.

For example, if you have a textbox that has to only contain numbers and a user enters a letter in that textbox. If your client side script generates an error message like " 'somevalue' is an invalid value for this textbox ", then you are injecting whatever the user has entered into the box back onto the page. Either way, it will only affect that user's session.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'm just validating against my model before deciding whether to save to the database, so any hiccups will affect only that user, I think.

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS validate and sanitize before submitting to the database.  Without doing so, you could expose your database to SQL injection attacks.

What order you do so depends on what you want your user experience to be.  If you validate first, then you could provide validation back to the user easier (You could use javascript and regular expressions to do this)

Required xkcd cartoon:

[image]